# How can I pass the subdomain as a value to search for a record in Rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

I want to be able to send users to the following styled-URL:

subdomain.mydomain.com/tag

I have a LandingPage record, and so would like to be able to search for the specific LandingPage record by matching the method LandingPage.subdomain with the value in subdomain.

I would then want to store the value found in tag when someone submits a form on that page.

How can I do this without creating in my DNS or in Zerigo the specific subdomain in the URL?  I'd like it to respond to a wildcard, but use the value to do a record search of an ActiveRecord.

Comment: Are you using apache/passenger?

Comment: I am going to be hosting it on heroku and use webrick in development

Answer (score 0):

Ryan does something very similar in his Railcast on subdomains:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Comment: Sorry, just read the 'Rails 2' in your question title.  Fortunately, Ryan had a previous Rails 2 screencast on subdomains as well: http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains